# Faceless insulation

Tags: insulation

I live in Central MN and have a garage which has a finished garage with an unfinished attic above. There are floor boards in the attic which I pulled up to find no insulation. I understand it would be best to use faced insulation however I got a real good deal on faceless.  My question is would I want to put plastic down on top of the sheetrock then lay down the faceless insulation or would there be a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: humidity barriers are always good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

It would be very hard to get a vapor barrier with faced insulation in this instance; the ceiling is the warm side and that is where you need a vapor barrier and laying faced insulation upside down (since you have the attic side exposed) will never allow an airtight installation.

Plastic would be easier to do by cutting it to fit and taping (use a good air sealing tape, not duct or packaging) it so there is no air leaks/movement allowed and then placing the faceless batts, and then putting the floor boards back on. Be sure to brush and vacuum the bays before hand to get a good adhesion with the tape.

Another option, although expensive, would be closed cell insulation, but since you already have the faceless insulation and plastic is cheap, I think plastic+tape+faceless insulation is a fine way to do it.